# subeclipse not showing same version as svn

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Slight oddness going on with svn...

I checked out a repositry with subclipse inside eclipse - the history looks like this: 
[image]

But when I update on the command line, I get this:

```
pool188-239$svn up
At revision 1908.
```

Can anyone tell me why the version numbers are different for the same project?

Comment: Run svn log --limit 1 from the command line.  You will likely see that r1906 was the last revision where this path was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revision 1906 is the revision where your project was last modified.

Revision 1908 is the current revision of Subversion.  When you do an update on your project, the revision number returned is the current revision of Subversion.